# How do I remove the /region/ from my permalinks?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm working on a website where users can search for tattoo shops in specific cities. When they want to search for a tattoo shop in Amsterdam, the permalink looks like this: https://www.tattoofinders.nl/region/amsterdam/

The /region/ part seems like unnecessary bloat in the permalink and I want to remove this.

I tried to go to Wordpress > settings > permalink to delete the 'region' part, but I have to fill in something, or else the default value will be used, which is 'region'. https://prnt.sc/t9sdyp

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Question already answered here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls

Beware that the cpt slug is useful to have a faster website, since WP knows what to search for.
If you remove it WP has to search between posts and cpt posts, thats way more slower.

In addition, if you use the same permalink for both stardard post or cpt post something may get weird.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly you would advise to just leave the slug in the URL? I wanted to remove it for SEO purposes, but I am doubting now.

Comment: I'm a SEO specialist and I've to say that removing that is not gonna help you in any way, that's an old misconception.

Can only make your permalink more readable in some project, but that doesn't seem to be your case.